# Golang regexp not greedy when multiline

Tags: regex, go

In the following code [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/jkoaYnnKRB):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    s := `aaa
    token
    token
    bbb` 
    R := regexp.MustCompile(`.*token`)
    m := R.FindStringSubmatch(s)
    fmt.Println(len(m)) // 1
    for _, v := range m {
        fmt.Println(v) //    token
    }

    R = regexp.MustCompile(`^.*token`)
    m = R.FindStringSubmatch(s)
    fmt.Println(len(m)) // 0
}
```

I expect the first regex to match

```
aaa
    token
    token
```

And in the second case it should be the same. However in the first case I'm only getting     `token` and int the second case nothing at all.

Comment: Prepend the pattern with `(?s)`: `\`(?s)^.*token\``

Comment: That's it. Thanks!